# AngularJS / Repeat SubElement

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have elements construct like this :

```
elements = [{
    class: 'class1',
    subject: 'name1',
    students : [{ Name : Toto  } , {Name : Tata}]
}, {
    class: 'class2',
    subject: 'name2',
    students : [{ Name : Titi  } , {Name : Tutu}]
}];
```

I want to show element and students in a commun table like this but i think it's not possible with multi ng-repeat ?

```
<tr><td>class1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Toto</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tata</td></tr>

<tr><td>class2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Titi</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tutu</td></tr>
```

The real code...

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="actionController">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Commentaire</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Visuel</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="section in Sections" class="info">
            <td>{{section.label}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

       <tr ng-repeat="chapiter in section.chapiters">
            <td>{{chapiter.label}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**I find the solution here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/nk3ta/**

Comment: The fiddle is working

Comment: create a fiddle of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. Tested in `AngularJS v 1.2.21`

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in elements">
        <td>{{item.class}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="s in item.students">
        <td>{{s.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gtjmwd4/1/)**